# How to split an xts object in multiple ways?

Tags: r, split, xts

I have the following data:

```
xtsdata <- structure(c(0.44696179, 0.395227931, 0.477439822, 0.295309508, 
  0.712614891, 0.689317114, 0.599395023, 0.610971864, 0.337625508, 0.529290134,
  0.596002106, 0.412324483, 0.244831259, 0.443123542, 0.484748065, 0.686165972,
  0.711764909, 0.604578061, 0.42144923, 0.669898641, 0.735845192, 0.592157589,
  0.81714156, 0.380346873, 0.684386001, 0.672967504, 0.508142689, 0.244274776,
  0.548213564, 0.417804342, 0.612475603, 0.665148957, 0.756447435, 0.582448567,
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.71708817, 0.528262036, 0.597354154, 0.886971243, 0.624771744,
  0.498557661, 0.382554107, 0.464373083, 0.425888914, 0.747806533, 0.788271626,
  0.407617084, 0.784747938, 0.466987506, 0.554976586, 0.621751352, 0.501173993,
  0.323827823, 0.659625721, 0.502665703, 0.626577183, 0.458883576, 0.572507952,
  0.388946538, 0.897384403, 0.784054708, 0.652210478, 0.850226608, 0.514172118,
  0.780114865, 0.710307692, 0.714749488, 0.248817293, 0.576462902, 0.690210031),
  class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC",
  tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1288828800, 1288915200, 1289174400, 1289260800,
  1289347200, 1289433600, 1289520000, 1289779200, 1289865600, 1289952000,
  1290038400, 1290124800, 1290384000, 1290470400, 1290556800), tzone = "UTC",
  tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(15L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Stock1", "Stock10",
  "Stock100", "Stock101", "Stock102")))
```

I can split this by week like so:

```
xtslist <- split(xtsdata, f="weeks")
```

and that outputs a list of groups of 5 days.

The first thing I would like to know is how can I use the `split` or `split.xts` function to determine my own interval (for example 3).

Second, I need a function which would split `xtsdata` using a window of 10 but an interval of 5. So the first element in the list would contain the first 5 periods, the second would contain periods 0 to 10, and the third element will contain periods 5 to 15.

Comment: You can do something very similar to this function in my [imputation package](https://github.com/alexWhitworth/imputation/blob/master/R/create_canopies.R) (still in development)... I don't have time to figure out how to manipulate it for `xts` objects, which I rarely use

Comment: You need to clarify what you need the second function to do.  You mention "period 0" and "periods 5 to 15", but your example `xtsdata` only has 15 rows. So it's not clear whether period 0 refers to row 1 and period 15 should refer to row 16, or something else. Regardless, it would be much more helpful if you actually provide an example of what you expect the output to be, instead of just a description.